# How do I find all subdirectories in an S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I want to list all subdirectories with an empty or some prefix.
The parameters I tried is `prefix=""` and `delimiter="/"`
but this returns only the "plain files" in the bucket, not the "directories".

With delimiter="" I get everything.

SOLUTION:

The "directories" delimited by the `delimiter` are not listed in the keys, but in the common prefix part of the answer. There I can find my "directories" now.

Comment: What tools are you using to query s3?

Comment: I try to use it with the golang api